# Use images inside SharePoint Online 2013 inside a ASP.NET applicatioin

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, asp.net

I have SharePoint Online 2013 website up and running `https://testapp.sharepoint.com/` and inside `https://testapp.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC` I have folder set which contain images. And I have a separate hosted ASP.NET MVC application I want to show SharePoint images inside ASP.net application.  What would be the best solution to do that.

Comment: Access the SharePoint API via CSOM to get the images to show.